# Encountering 404 Error When Posting Registration Data to Server Endpoint in React Application

Tags: node.js, axios, http-status-code-404, registration

POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/register 404 (Not Found)

```
const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/user/register", values);
        if (res.data.success) {
            message.success("Registered Successfully!");
            navigate("/login");
        } else {
            message.error(res.data.message);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        message.error("Registration failed: " + error.message);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make sure your endpoint is configure(there might be some typos etc etc.)
2.) instead of axios, use fetch and see whether it works or not
3.) setup cors correctly